# Django if statement

Tags: django

Is it possible to use this code

```
{% if item.status == "0" %}
                <td>Pending</td>
            {% else %}
                <td>Approved</td>
            {% endif %}
```

if the item.status is an integer?
It seems to never go into the if statement and prints else all the time
Should i declare the variable first? eg something = item.status?

If yes then what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the 0 and it looks like it should work. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-if)

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing it to a string "0", not am integer 0. That's the problem. The syntax is fine, just remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

this should work.

```
{% ifequal item.status 0 %}
     <td>Pending</td>
{% else %}
     <td>Approved</td>
{% endifequal %}
```

**Edit**

just to clarify (as the other answers have mentioned) the issue is "0", comparing int == string, ifequal is just my preferred way of using the template tag.

Comment: Thank you! It did work :) I was looking at the django docs for ages and the only two i found where for integers and strings only in an if form